# Android KeyEvent getSize or getPressure

Tags: android

Is there a way to `getSize()` and `getPressure()` from a KeyEvent like you would with a MotionEvent?

In other words, MotionEvents have `getSize()` and `getPressure()` methods, but KeyEvents do not have these methods. Moreover, MotionEvents and KeyEvents are sibling classes, so they KeyEvent doesn't inherit these methods.

Comment: no i don't think there is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html. I misunderstood the question and posted a wrong answer